# How do I check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need to check the `checked` property of a checkbox and perform an action based on the checked property using jQuery.

For example, if the `age` checkbox is checked, then I need to show a textbox to enter `age`, else hide the textbox.

But the following code returns `false` by default:

```js
if ($('#isAgeSelected').attr('checked')) {
  $("#txtAge").show();
} else {
  $("#txtAge").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected"/>
<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">
  Age is selected
</div>
```

How do I successfully query the `checked` property?

Comment: Starting jquery 1.6 there have been significant changes the way attributes and properties are dealt with. For your case following should work:
if($('#isAgeSelected').prop("checked")) {
    $("#txtAge").show();
} else {
    $("#txtAge").hide();
}

 The condition in if statement will simply return true or false depending upon the checked/unchecked state of the check box. For more details refer to attributes vs. properties section on [this](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a checkbox is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/how-can-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$get("isAgeSelected ").checked == true
```

Where `isAgeSelected` is the id of the control.

Also, @karim79's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery/901727#901727) works fine. I am not sure what I missed at the time I tested it.

**Note, this is answer uses Microsoft Ajax, not jQuery**

Comment: The question specifically requests for a jQuery solution.

Comment: Not useful info for the question that specifically asked about jQuery.

Answer (score 3670):

> How do I successfully query the checked property?

The `checked` property of a checkbox DOM element will give you the `checked` state of the element.

Given your existing code, you could therefore do this:

```
if(document.getElementById('isAgeSelected').checked) {
    $("#txtAge").show();
} else {
    $("#txtAge").hide();
}
```

However, there's a much prettier way to do this, using [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```js
$('#isAgeSelected').click(function() {
    $("#txtAge").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected"/>
<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">Age is something</div>
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. `this.checked` is not jQuery, as the OP asked for. Also, it only works when user clicks on the checkbox, which is not part of the question. The question is, again, `How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?` at any given time with or without clicking the checkbox and in jQuery.

Comment: How would “is not jQuery” be an argument? That attitude is quite harmful and the reason why it’s so hard to get rid of jQuery nowadays! If you can use vanilla JavaScript from ages ago, which works everywhere and is in no way more complicated to use or longer to write, you should definitely do so.

Comment: Not only that but jquery is a javascript extension, and therefore contains all of javascript.  .  In any case "this" is a jquery object so he's completely wrong anyway.

Comment: "How would 'is not jquery' be an argument?" Because, while you can indeed use both jquery and plain js on the same script, it's more readable if you use *one* coding style rather than two. And if you already accepted the jquery tradeoffs, you may as well use it.

Comment: People don't code in jquery exclusively.  you can't.  In any case, jquery isn't a language.  It's a library, and you merely have to look at code for checkboxes specifically to see that the programmers can't make up their mind how to set/unset even a simple common control.  I just finished fixing one of our site's pages because jquery versions changed and attr no longer worked on checkboxes.  javascript doesn't have that problem and the only reason we have jquery at all in our project is it is required by our kendo libraries.

Answer (score 2253):

Use jQuery's [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function:

```
if($("#isAgeSelected").is(':checked'))
    $("#txtAge").show();  // checked
else
    $("#txtAge").hide();  // unchecked
```

Comment: A little bit cleaner solution would be `$("#txtAge").toggle($("#isAgeSelected").is(':checked'))`.

Comment: @KaiNeuwerth IMO it's not cleaner, just shorter.

Comment: f($("#isAgeSelected").is(':checked'))

Answer (score 653):

Using jQuery > 1.6

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkMeOut" id="checkMeOut" checked="checked" />

// traditional attr
$('#checkMeOut').attr('checked'); // "checked"
// new property method
$('#checkMeOut').prop('checked'); // true
```

Using the new property method:

```
if($('#checkMeOut').prop('checked')) {
    // something when checked
} else {
    // something else when not
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you have a `<input type="hidden" value="0" name="checkMeOut">` alongside the checkbox like several frameworks do in order to always submit a value. `.is(':checked')` on the other hand works in that case.

Answer (score 274):

**jQuery 1.6+**

```
$('#isAgeSelected').prop('checked')
```

**jQuery 1.5 and below**

```
$('#isAgeSelected').attr('checked')
```

**Any version of jQuery**

```
// Assuming an event handler on a checkbox
if (this.checked)
```

All credit goes to [Xian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426276/443427).

Comment: Technically, `this.checked` is using straight Javascript.  But I love that cross-jQuery-version answer!

Comment: Doesn't work if you have a `<input type="hidden" value="0" name="checkMeOut">` alongside the checkbox like several frameworks do in order to always submit a value. `.is(':checked')` on the other hand works in that case.

Answer (score 193):

I am using this and this is working absolutely fine:

```
$("#checkkBoxId").attr("checked") ? alert("Checked") : alert("Unchecked");
```

Note: If the checkbox is checked it will return true otherwise undefined, so better check for the "TRUE" value.

Comment: `attr` gives undefined for me, but `prop` seems to work fine.

Answer (score 178):

Use:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked" checked id="planned_checked"> Planned

$("#planned_checked").change(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        alert("Checked Box Selected");
    } else {
        alert("Checked Box deselect");
    }
});
```

```js
    $("#planned_checked").change(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            alert("Checked Box Selected");
        } else {
            alert("Checked Box deselect");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked" checked id="planned_checked"> Planned
```

Answer (score 135):

Since jQuery 1.6, the behavior of [`jQuery.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) has changed and users are encouraged  not to use it to retrieve an element's checked state. Instead, you should use [`jQuery.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$("#txtAge").toggle(
    $("#isAgeSelected").prop("checked") // For checked attribute it returns true/false;
                                        // Return value changes with checkbox state
);
```

Two other possibilities are:

```
$("#txtAge").get(0).checked
$("#txtAge").is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 112):

If you are using an updated version of jquery, you must go for `.prop` method to resolve your issue:

`$('#isAgeSelected').prop('checked')` will return `true` if checked and `false` if unchecked. I confirmed it and I came across this issue earlier. `$('#isAgeSelected').attr('checked')` and `$('#isAgeSelected').is('checked')` is returning `undefined` which is not a worthy answer for the situation. So do as given below.

```
if($('#isAgeSelected').prop('checked')) {
    $("#txtAge").show();
} else {
    $("#txtAge").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 76):

Use:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" value="UDB">UDB
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" value="Prasad">Prasad
```

```
$('input#abc').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
    var checkedOne=$(this).val()
    alert(checkedOne);

    // Do some other action
  }
})
```

This can help if you want that the required action has to be done only when you check the box not at the time you remove the check.

Answer (score 73):

You can try the `change` event of checkbox to track the `:checked` state change.

```js
$("#isAgeSelected").on('change', function() {
  if ($("#isAgeSelected").is(':checked'))
    alert("checked");
  else {
    alert("unchecked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected" />
<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">
  Age is selected
</div>
```

Answer (score 70):

Using the `Click` event handler for the checkbox property is unreliable, as the `checked` property can change during the execution of the event handler itself!

Ideally, you'd want to put your code into a `change` event handler such as it is fired every time the value of the check box is changed (independent of *how* it's done so).

```
$('#isAgeSelected').bind('change', function () {

   if ($(this).is(':checked'))
     $("#txtAge").show();
   else
     $("#txtAge").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 64):

I ran in to the exact same issue. I have an ASP.NET checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox1" CssClass='cssChkBox1' runat="server" />
```

In the jQuery code I used the following selector to check if the checkbox was checked or not, and it seems to work like a charm.

```
if ($("'.cssChkBox1 input[type=checkbox]'").is(':checked'))
{ ... } else { ... }
```

I'm sure you can also use the ID instead of the CssClass,

```
if ($("'#cssChkBox1 input[type=checkbox]'").is(':checked'))
{ ... } else { ... }
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: you _can_ use the css class, as long as you keep in mind that css classes aren't meant to be unique. If you want to respond to changes in a single element then ID would be the preffered way to go.

Answer (score 62):

I believe you could do this:

```
if ($('#isAgeSelected :checked').size() > 0)
{
    $("#txtAge").show(); 
} else { 
    $("#txtAge").hide();
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer for selecting ONLY those that are checked in the first place.
$('#isAgeSelected :checked')

Answer (score 62):

I decided to post an answer on how to do that exact same thing without jQuery. Just because I'm a rebel.

```
var ageCheckbox = document.getElementById('isAgeSelected');
var ageInput = document.getElementById('txtAge');

// Just because of IE <333
ageCheckbox.onchange = function() {
    // Check if the checkbox is checked, and show/hide the text field.
    ageInput.hidden = this.checked ? false : true;
};
```

First you get both elements by their ID. Then you assign the checkboxe's `onchange` event a function that checks whether the checkbox got checked and sets the `hidden` property of the age text field appropriately. In that example using the ternary operator.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mainerror/cjSkC/) for you to test it.

**Addendum**

If cross-browser compatibility is an issue then I propose to set the CSS `display` property to *none* and *inline*.

```
elem.style.display = this.checked ? 'inline' : 'none';
```

Slower but cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 60):

**This code will help you**

```
$('#isAgeSelected').click(function(){
   console.log(this.checked);
   if(this.checked == true) {
        $("#txtAge").show();
    } else {
       $("#txtAge").hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 57):

This works for me:

```
/* isAgeSelected being id for checkbox */

$("#isAgeSelected").click(function(){
  $(this).is(':checked') ? $("#txtAge").show() : $("#txtAge").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 54):

There are many ways to check if a checkbox is checked or not:

Way to check using jQuery

```
if (elem.checked)
if ($(elem).prop("checked"))
if ($(elem).is(":checked"))
if ($(elem).attr('checked'))
```

Check example or also document:

- http://api.jquery.com/attr/
- http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 50):

This is some different method to do the same thing:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#isAgeSelected').click(function() {
        // $("#txtAge").toggle(this.checked);

        // Using a pure CSS selector
        if ($(this.checked)) {
            alert('on check 1');
        };

        // Using jQuery's is() method
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('on checked 2');
        };

        //  // Using jQuery's filter() method
        if ($(this).filter(':checked')) {
            alert('on checked 3');
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected"/>
<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">Age is something</div>
```

Answer (score 44):

Use this:

```
if ($('input[name="salary_in.Basic"]:checked').length > 0)
```

The length is greater than zero if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 39):

My way of doing this is:

```
if ( $("#checkbox:checked").length ) {       
    alert("checkbox is checked");
} else {
    alert("checkbox is not checked");
}
```

Answer (score 36):

```
$(selector).attr('checked') !== undefined
```

This returns `true` if the input is checked and `false` if it is not.

Answer (score 35):

You can use:

```
  if(document.getElementById('isAgeSelected').checked)
    $("#txtAge").show();  
  else
    $("#txtAge").hide();
```

---

```
if($("#isAgeSelected").is(':checked'))
  $("#txtAge").show();  
else
  $("#txtAge").hide();
```

Both of them should work.

Answer (score 34):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#agecheckbox').click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $('#agetextbox').show();
        } else {
            $('#agetextbox').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 32):

**1) If your HTML markup is:**

```
<input type="checkbox"  />
```

attr used:

```
$(element).attr("checked"); // Will give you undefined as initial value of checkbox is not set
```

If prop is used:

```
$(element).prop("checked"); // Will give you false whether or not initial value is set
```

**2) If your HTML markup is:**

```
 <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" />// May be like this also  checked="true"
```

attr used:

```
$(element).attr("checked") // Will return checked whether it is checked="true"
```

Prop used:

```
$(element).prop("checked") // Will return true whether checked="checked"
```

Comment: This is a REAL problem. My workaround - add a change event to the input: <input type="checkbox" onchange="ChangeChkBox()" /> then use that event to change a boolean JavaScript variable, and use the JavaScript variable instead of querying the checkbox directly.

Answer (score 29):

To act on a checkbox being checked or unchecked on click.

```js
$('#customCheck1').click(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log('checked');
  } else {
    console.log('un-checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="customCheck1">
```

EDIT: Not a nice programming expression `if (boolean == true)` though `.checked` property might return other type variables as well..

It is better to use `.prop("checked")` instead. It returns `true` and `false` only.

Comment: Note that `this.checked` will **not work on a Jquery object** as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21123921/1526703). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58215046/1526703) would work (i.e `$(this).is(":checked")`)

Answer (score 28):

The top answer didn't do it for me. This did though:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#li_13").click(function(){
            if($("#agree").attr('checked')){
                $("#saveForm").fadeIn();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#saveForm").fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Basically when the element #li_13 is clicked, it checks if the element # agree (which is the checkbox) is checked by using the `.attr('checked')` function. If it is then fadeIn the #saveForm element, and if not fadeOut the saveForm element.

Answer (score 28):

This example is for button.

Try the following:

```
<input type="button" class="check" id="checkall" value="Check All" />  &nbsp; <input type="button" id="remove" value="Delete" /> <br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element"  value="1" /> Checkbox  1 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element"  value="2" /> Checkbox  2 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element"  value="3" /> Checkbox  3 <br/>


$('#remove').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 

$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('.cb-element').click(function() {

        if($(this).prop('checked'))
        {
            $('#remove').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#remove').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });   

    $('.check:button').click(function()
{
    var checked = !$(this).data('checked');
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
    $(this).data('checked', checked);

    if(checked == true)
    {
        $(this).val('Uncheck All');
         $('#remove').attr('disabled', false);
    }

    else if(checked == false)
    {
        $(this).val('Check All');
        $('#remove').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 28):

Though you have proposed a JavaScript solution for your problem (displaying a `textbox` when a `checkbox` is `checked`), this problem could be solved **just by css**. With this approach, your form works for users who have disabled JavaScript.

Assuming that you have the following HTML:

```
<label for="show_textbox">Show Textbox</label>
<input id="show_textbox" type="checkbox" />
<input type="text" />
```

You can use the following CSS to achieve the desired functionality:

```
 #show_textbox:not(:checked) + input[type=text] {display:none;}
```

For other scenarios, you may think of appropriate CSS selectors.

[Here is a Fiddle to demonstrate this approach](https://jsfiddle.net/gLztyn9x/4/).

Answer (score 27):

I am using this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected" value="1" /> <br/>
 <input type="textbox" id="txtAge" />

 $("#isAgeSelected").is(':checked') ? $("#txtAge").show() : $("#txtAge").hide();
```

Answer (score 24):

Toggle: 0/1 or else

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nolunch" />
<input id="checklunch />"

    $('#nolunch').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#checklunch').val('1');
    };
    if ($(this).is(':checked') == false) {
        $('#checklunch').val('0');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 23):

I think it will be the simple one

```
$('#isAgeSelected').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#txtAge').show();
    }
else{
        $('#txtAge').hide();
    }                                          
});
```

Answer (score 23):

**Please try below code to check checkbox is checked or not**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#isAgeSelected").on('change',function(){

    if($("#isAgeSelected").is(':checked'))
        $("#txtAge").show();  // checked
    else{
        $("#txtAge").hide();  // unchecked
    }

   });

});
```

Answer (score 20):

I'm sure it's not some revelation, but I didn't see it all in one example:

Selector for all checked checkboxes(on the page):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
```

Answer (score 19):

I verified in Firefox 9.0.1 that the following works for catching the state of a checkbox post change:

```
$("#mycheckbox").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).prop("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';                     
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 17):

Include jQuery from the local file system. I used Google's [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), and there are also many CDNs to choose from.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The code will execute as soon as a checkbox inside `mycheck` class is clicked. If the current clicked checkbox is checked then it will disable all others and enable the current one. If the current one is unchecked, it will again enable all checkboxes for rechecking.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var checkbox_selector = '.mycheck input[type=checkbox]';

        $(checkbox_selector).click(function() {
            if ($($(this)).is(':checked')) {

                // Disable all checkboxes
                $(checkbox_selector).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                // Enable current one
                $($(this)).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            else {
                // If unchecked open all checkbox
                $(checkbox_selector).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Simple form to test

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="mycheck">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" /> Television
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" /> Computer
        <input type="checkbox" value="3" /> Laptop
        <input type="checkbox" value="4" /> Camera
        <input type="checkbox" value="5" /> Music Systems
    </div>
</form>
```

Output screen:

[image]

Answer (score 17):

```
if($("#checkkBoxId").is(':checked')){
  alert("Checked=true");
}
```

or

```
if($("#checkkBoxId").attr('checked') == true){
  alert("checked=true");
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The `checked` attribute of an `input type="checkbox"` is mapped with the `defaultChecked` property, **not** with the `checked` property.

So when doing something in a page when a checkbox is checked on uncheked, use the `prop()` method instead. It fetches the property value and changes as the state of the checkbox changes.

Using `attr(`) or `getAttribute`(in pure JavaScript) in these cases are not the proper way of doing things.

if `elem` is the concerned checkbox then do something like this to fetch the value:

```
elem.checked
```

or

```
$(elem).prop('checked')
```

Answer (score 15):

#### Automated

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#isAgeSelected').change(function()
    {
        alert( 'value =' + $('#chkSelect').attr('checked') );
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<b> <input type="isAgeSelected" id="chkSelect" /> Age Check </b>

<br/><br/>

<input type="button" id="btnCheck" value="check" />
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#btnCheck').click(function()
    {
        var isChecked = $('#isAgeSelected').attr('checked');

        if (isChecked == 'checked')
            alert('check-box is checked');
        else
            alert('check-box is not checked');
    })
});
```

**Ajax**

```
function check()
{
    if (isAgeSelected())
        alert('check-box is checked');
    else
        alert('check-box is not checked');
}

function isAgeSelected()
{
    return ($get("isAgeSelected").checked == true);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```js
$(document).on("click","#isAgeSelected",function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
    $("#txtAge").show();
  }
  else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
    $("#txtAge").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected"/>

<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Please enter age" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

This is the minimal amount of code I think I needed to do something like this effectively. I found this method to be useful; it returns an array of the check boxes that are checked and then you can use their value (this solution uses jQuery):

```
// This is how you get them
var output = "";
var checkedBoxes = $("DivCheckBoxesAreIn").children("input:checked");
if(checkedBoxes.length <= 0) {
    alert('Please select check boxes');
    return false;
};

// And this is how you use them:
checkedBoxes.each(function() {
    output +=  this.value + ", ";
};
```

Printing "output" will give you a comma-separated list of your values.

Answer (score 14):

Using pure **JavaScript**:

```
let checkbox = document.getElementById('checkboxID');

if(checkbox.checked) {
  alert('is checked');
} else {
  alert('not checked yet');
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same problem and none of the posted solutions seemed to work and then I found out that it's because ASP.NET renders the CheckBox control as a SPAN with INPUT inside, so the CheckBox ID is actually an ID of a SPAN, not an INPUT, so you should use:

```
$('#isAgeSelected input')
```

rather than

```
$('#isAgeSelected')
```

and then all methods listed above should work.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example that includes **initialising** the show/hide to match the state of the checkbox when the **page loads**; taking account of the fact that firefox *remembers the state of checkboxes* when you refresh the page, but *won't* remember the state of the shown/hidden elements.

```
$(function() {
    // initialise visibility when page is loaded
    $('tr.invoiceItemRow').toggle($('#showInvoiceItems').attr('checked'));
    // attach click handler to checkbox
    $('#showInvoiceItems').click(function(){ $('tr.invoiceItemRow').toggle(this.checked);})
});
```

(with help from other answers on this question)

Answer (score 13):

Simply use it like below

```
 $('#isAgeSelected').change(function() {
     if ($(this).is(":checked")) { // or if($("#isAgeSelected").attr('checked') == true){
         $('#txtAge').show();
     } else {
         $('#txtAge').hide();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 10):

This was my workaround:

```
$('#vcGoButton').click(function () {
    var buttonStatus = $('#vcChangeLocation').prop('checked');
    console.log("Status is " + buttonStatus);
    if (buttonStatus) {
        var address = $('#vcNewLocation').val();
        var cabNumber = $('#vcVehicleNumber').val();
        $.get('postCabLocation.php',
              {address: address, cabNumber: cabNumber},
              function(data) {
                  console.log("Changed vehicle " + cabNumber + " location to " + address );
              });
    }
    else {
        console.log("VC go button clicked, but no location action");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Setter:

```
$("#chkmyElement")[0].checked = true;
```

Getter:

```
if($("#chkmyElement")[0].checked) {
   alert("enabled");
} else {
   alert("disabled");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
$(this).toggle($("input:checkbox", $(this))[0].checked);
```

When you are selecting out of context, remember you need the [0] to access the checkbox.

Answer (score 8):

I would actually prefere the `change` event.

```
$('#isAgeSelected').change(function() {
    $("#txtAge").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/6913/)

Answer (score 8):

A selector returns multiple objects, and it must take the first item in the array:

```
// Collection
var chckremember = $("#chckremember");


// Result boolen
var ischecked=chckremember[0].checked;
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
$('#isAgeSelected').click(function() {
    if(this.checked){
        $("#txtAge").show();
    } else{
        $("#txtAge").hide();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not merely solving the problem at hand, but also educating the OP and any future readers of this question and answer. Thus, please [edit] the answer to include an explanation as to why it works.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1 and I had troubles with setting and reading checkbox value as well.

I finally solved it by these two functions:

```
function setCheckboxValue(checkBoxId, checked) {
    if (checkBoxId && (checked === true || checked === false)) {
        var elem = $('#' + checkBoxId);
        if (checked === true) {
            elem.attr('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            elem.removeAttr('checked');
        }
    }
}

function isChecked(checkBoxId) {
    return $('#' + checkBoxId).attr('checked') != null;
}
```

It might looks a little bit dirty but it solves all the wired issue I had among different types of browsers.

Answer (score 7):

You Can Try This code:

```
$('#isAgeSelected').click(function(){
   console.log(this.checked);
   if(this.checked == true) {
        $("#txtAge").show();
    } else {
       $("#txtAge").hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not merely solving the problem at hand, but also educating the OP and any future readers of this question and answer. Thus, please [edit] the answer to include an explanation as to why it works.

Answer (score 6):

```
if( undefined == $('#isAgeSelected').attr('checked') ) {
    $("#txtAge").hide();
} else {
    $("#txtAge").show();
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not merely solving the problem at hand, but also educating the OP and any future readers of this question and answer. Thus, please [edit] the answer to include an explanation as to why it works.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).on('change', '#isAgeSelected', function() {

    if($(this).is(":checked")){

       $('#txtAge').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#txtAge').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Hi you can use plain `Javascript`, like so:

```js
document.getElementById('checkboxOption').addEventListener('click',      
   event => console.log(event.target.checked)
);
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxOption">Check Option</label>
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not merely solving the problem at hand, but also educating the OP and any future readers of this question and answer. Thus, please [edit] the answer to include an explanation as to why it works.

Answer (score 4):

What about this solution?

```
$("#txtAge")[
    $("#isAgeSelected").is(':checked') ?
    'show' :
    'hide'
]();
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not merely solving the problem at hand, but also educating the OP and any future readers of this question and answer. Thus, please [edit] the answer to include an explanation as to why it works.

Answer (score 4):

I need to check the checked property of a checkbox and perform an action based on the checked property using jQuery.

E.X -

1) Run On load to get checkbox value if the age checkbox is checked, then I need to show a text box to enter age, else hide the text box.

2) if the age checkbox is checked, then I need to show a text box to enter age, else hide the text box using click event of checkbox.

**so code not returns false by default:**

Try the following:

```
<html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Jquery Demo</h1>
            <input type="checkbox" name="isAge" checked id="isAge"> isAge <br/>
            <div id="Age" style="display:none">
              <label>Enter your age</label>
              <input type="number" name="age">
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            if(document.getElementById('isAge').checked) {
                $('#Age').show();
            } else {
                $('#Age').hide();
            }   
            $('#isAge').click(function() {
                if(document.getElementById('isAge').checked) {
                    $('#Age').show();
                } else {
                    $('#Age').hide();
                }
            }); 
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is a modified version : https://jsfiddle.net/sedhal/0hygLtrz/7/

Answer (score 4):

In pure js checkbox state is easier to read

```
isAgeSelected.checked
```

```js
function check() {
  txtAge.style.display= isAgeSelected.checked ? 'block':'none';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Age <input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected"/>

<button onclick="check()">Check</button>

<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">
Age is selected
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to know if a checkbox is checked in pure `javascript` you should use this code .

```
let checkbox =document.getElementById('myCheckboxId');
if(checkbox.checked) {
    alert("element is checked");
} else {
    alert("element is  ot checked");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try the followings in both ways:

```
var getVal=$('#isAgeSelected').is(":checked"); // jQuery

var getVal=document.getElementById("isAgeSelected").checked //JavaScript

if (getVal==true) {
 $("#txtAge").show();  // checked
} else {
 $("#txtAge").hide();  // unchecked
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if( undefined == $('#isAgeSelected').attr('checked') ) {
    $("#txtAge").hide();
} else {
    $("#txtAge").show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For older versions of jQuery, I had to use following,

```
$('#change_plan').live('click', function() {
     var checked = $('#change_plan').attr('checked');
     if(checked) {
          //Code       
     }
     else {
          //Code       
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you need to use CSS class as jQuery selector you can do following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.myOptionCheckbox').change(function () {            
            if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
                console.log("checked");           
            }
            else {
                console.log("unchecked");                
            }
        });
    });
```

It works fine for `checkboxes` and `radioboxes` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This function is alternative and stable:

```
$('#isAgeSelected').context.checked
(return True/False)
```

***Example:***

```
if($('#isAgeSelected').context.checked){ //if Checkbox is checked then bla bla..
    /*.....*/
}else{
    /*.....*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#chk').change(function() { 
    (this.checked)? alert('true') : alert('false');
});



($('#chk')[0].checked)? alert('true') : alert('false');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#isAgeSelected').prop('checked')) {
    // do your action 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`$("#isAgeSelected").prop('checked', true);`

Comment: This code can set the checkbox to checked status.I do not think this answer is relative to the question.